# Why does Chrome take longer to resolve new DNS entries when ping and nslookup works immediately?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, nslookup

I have an internal DNS server with a TTL set to 300.

Whenever I add a new host, the command line `ping` and `nslookup` commands work immediately and resolve the new address without issue.

However in Chrome, it takes 5-10 minutes to begin resolving the address.

It doesn't matter if I clear Chrome's DNS cache at `chrome://net-internals/#dns` I simply have to wait a while in order for the new domain name to resolve.

This is reproducible on different systems using Chrome.

Is there a hidden cache I need to clear or a "force refresh" option I'm missing? Does anyone know why it behaves like this? I haven't tried a different browser to compare behavior yet, but I will shortly.

Comment: is your Chrome using a proxy at all?

Comment: For what it's worth, a TTL of 300 is approximately 5 minutes. Also, while it doesn't directly answer the question, I would say that I have seen this behavior in Firefox as well. Occasionally, clearing the cache repeatedly (and reloading the page in between clearings) *seems* to help..